# Error on retrieve data from Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I am new for android. Got problem on retrieve data from realm. I use retrofit, and want to save data using Realm(Successful for Sqlite ), but while retrieving the data from database i got some error which i have post it.

```
package np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.ui;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.List;

import np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.Controller.RestManager;
import np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.R;
import np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.model.Flower;
import np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.model.adapter.FlowerAdapter;
import np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.model.helper.Constants;
import np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.model.helper.FlowerDatabase;
import np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.model.helper.Utils;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity
        implements FlowerAdapter.FlowersClickListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RestManager mManager;
    FlowerAdapter mFlowerAdapter;
    FlowerDatabase mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        configViews();
        mManager = new RestManager();
        mDatabase = new FlowerDatabase();
        if(Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
            getFeed();
        } else {
            getFeedFromDatabase();
        }
    }

    private void getFeedFromDatabase() {
        Log.e("RetData", "RetData");
        List<Flower> flowerList = mDatabase.getFlower();
        for(int i = 0; i < flowerList.size(); i++) {
            Flower flower = flowerList.get(i);
            mFlowerAdapter.addFlower(flower);
        }
    }

    private void configViews() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());

        LinearLayoutManager verticalLayoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(verticalLayoutmanager);
        mFlowerAdapter = new FlowerAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mFlowerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if(id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(int position) {
        Flower selectedFlower = mFlowerAdapter.getSelectedFlower(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.REFERENCE.FLOWER, selectedFlower);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void getFeed() {
        Call<List<Flower>> listCall = mManager.getFlowerService().getAllFlowers();
        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Flower>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Flower>> call, Response<List<Flower>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Flower> flowerList = response.body();
                    for(int i = 0; i < flowerList.size(); i++) {
                        Flower flower = flowerList.get(i);

                        SaveIntoDatabase task = new SaveIntoDatabase();
                        task.execute(flower);
                        mFlowerAdapter.addFlower(flower);
                    }
                } else {
                    int st = response.code();
                    switch(st) {
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Flower>> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }

    public class SaveIntoDatabase
            extends AsyncTask<Flower, Flower, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Flower... params) {
            Flower flower = params[0];
            try {
                //InputStream stream = new URL("http://services.hanselandpetal.com/photos/" + flower.getPhoto()).openStream();
                // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                //flower.setPicture(bitmap);
                mDatabase.addFlower(flower);
                Log.e("ErrorAft", "ErrorAft");
            } catch(Exception e) {

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

FlowerDatabase

```
package np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.model.helper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmResults;
import np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.model.Flower;
import np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.model.adapter.FlowerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Rabindra on 8/12/2016.
 */
public class FlowerDatabase
        extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Realm myRealm;
    private int productID;
    private static FlowerDatabase flowerDatabase;
    private static List<Flower> arrayListFlower = new ArrayList<>();
    private FlowerAdapter flowerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        flowerDatabase = this;
    }

    public void addFlower(Flower model) {
        Log.e("RealmData", "RealmData");
        myRealm.beginTransaction();
        Flower flower = myRealm.createObject(Flower.class);
        flower.setProductId(model.getProductId());
        flower.setCategory(model.getCategory());
        flower.setName(model.getName());
        flower.setPrice(model.getPrice());
        flower.setInstruction(model.getInstruction());
        arrayListFlower.add(flower);
        myRealm.commitTransaction();
        flowerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public List<Flower> getFlower() {
        Flower model = new Flower();
        productID = model.getProductId();

        RealmResults<Flower> results = myRealm.where(Flower.class).findAll();
        myRealm.beginTransaction();

        for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            arrayListFlower.add(results.get(i));
        }
        if(results.size() > 0) {
            productID = myRealm.where(Flower.class).max("id").intValue() + 1;
        }
        myRealm.commitTransaction();
        flowerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return arrayListFlower;
    }
}
```

> Error LogCat:
>
> n E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                              Process: np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern, PID: 17091
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern/np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.ui.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2375)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:164)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1268)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5377)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                              at
>   np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.model.helper.FlowerDatabase.getFlower(FlowerDatabase.java:70)
>                                                                                              at
>   np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.ui.MainActivity.getFeedFromDatabase(MainActivity.java:69)
>                                                                                              at
>   np.com.rabindraacharya.retrofitintern.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5428)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2281)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2375) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:164) 
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1268) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5377) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: 1.) what version of Realm are you using, and 2.) what the hell did you intend to do in `FlowerDatabase` because that class is completely wrong.

Comment: Finally I solve the problem. Thanks fro your comment

Answer (score 0):

This line here `myRealm.where(Flower.class).max("id").intValue() + 1;` will throw a NullPointerException if no Flower objects exists. `max` returns `null` in that case: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#max-java.lang.String-

Comment: Can you explain more about it? I can't get point, and can't solve the problem that i got.

Comment: He had more fundamental problems than that.

Answer (score 0):

You might have attempted to extend `AppCompatActivity` with your `FlowerDatabase` class for no real valid reason, but `onCreate()` will never run because you instantiated the `flowerDatabase` with `mDatabase = new FlowerDatabase();`, and is therefore not managed by the system.

(This is not even supposed to be an Activity in the first place. Even if it were, you would have to create it with an `Intent`, like you do with any activity ever).

Technically, you should rewrite your code, because currently it's conceptually wrong.

Especially your `FlowerDatabase` class entirely, because you're misusing Realm as well.